# strtotime every refresh minutes and seconds change why

Tags: php

$order_startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // current date & time

```
$NewDate=Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 days", strtotime($order_startdate))); // 3 days increase Date And Time also

 var_dump($NewDate);
```

I am get string(19) `2015-06-29 06:56:42`

after refresh it has changed `2015-06-29 07:03:19`

I want the time do not changed time i want

$NewDate I'm Used in NextPayment Date in Subscription Payment

For Now 
i am in struggle !

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose you are using `$NewDate` ? If you can explain, someone might be able to give you a solution, this changes because time never stops!!

Comment: What is the value of variable `$order_startdate`??

Comment: $order_startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); it is a current date

Comment: this is why the date is changing you are adding 3 days to now $order_startdate should be unchanged for your $NewDate to remain unchanged.

Comment: $NewDate I'm Used in NextPayment Date in Subscription Payment

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Date() instance every time the script loads, which means that every time you refresh the page new time value is returned because of the nature of time (it changes over time :D)

If you want to save the time, that means, you need to write the value of your variable when it is created into database/somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Following from @Slim Kallari's answer, you could do this, to get a new date only when one is not already set:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['NewDate']))
{
   $NewDate=Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 days",   strtotime($order_startdate)));
   $_SESSION['NewDate'] = $NewDate;


}
else
{
    $NewDate= $_SESSION['NewDate'];
}

var_dump($NewDate);
```

That way, you create a new Date instance if one doesn't already exists. Make sure to add `session_start();` before creating your session variable, though.

Comment: did you remember to start your session using `session_start()`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I research myself and implemented as working solution finally here it is best instead of dom just remove dom and try it should did a trick

$date = $order->order_date;// checkout placeorder date

$trial = '1';

$subsc = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. '+ '. $trial . 'days'));